# How to set a radio button inside a list of expansion tile checked by default in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of expansion tiles and each of these tiles have 3 radio buttons each. I want to set some radio buttons checked by default when the page is loaded. How can I do this? Please help.

```
RadioButtonGroup(
              activeColor: Color(ProjectColors.mainColor),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "AN",
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Color(ProjectColors.secondaryColor),
              ),
              labels: _role.values.map((x) => x.title).toList(),
             )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is below:

```
String _picked = "Two"; //a variable _picked declared

RadioButtonGroup(
          orientation: GroupedButtonsOrientation.HORIZONTAL,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
          onSelected: (String selected) => setState((){
            _picked = selected;
          }),
          labels: <String>[
            "One",
            "Two",
          ],
          picked: _picked,
          itemBuilder: (Radio rb, Text txt, int i){
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.public),
                rb,
                txt,
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is this code applicable if I have a list of expansion tiles and in each tile there is 3 radio buttons and each radio button group in each tile must b different?

Comment: According to me this should work, just set its value same as the current groupValue

Comment: It works but not as I expected. When I select one radio button in one of the expansion tile all expansion tiles radio button is selected

Comment: Are you using: grouped_buttons

Comment: I am using  grouped_buttons

Comment: But i have a list of expansion tiles (each have 3 radio buttons) If picked is given like this when I select the first expansion tiles first radio button all of the expansion tiles first radio button will be picked. Any solution for that?

Comment: You will have to create 3 different lables for each expanded tile and declare a value for all the different tiles i.e for every group of 3 radio buttons you should have different "_picked" value